# Matlab Singularity

Tags: math, matlab, integral

I am having trouble in evaluating the following double integral:

Clearly the oscillating nature of the cos function is causing these issues. As I increase f and g to larger numbers, matlab complains of the singularities and the integration being unsuccessful.

```
(3 - 2*cos(y).*cos(f*x+g*y) - cos((f-1)*x + g*y)) ./ (4 - 2*cos(y).*(cos(y) + cos(x))) dxdy
```

Over limits -pi to pi for x and -pi to pi for y.

I have been using:

```
quad2d(@(x,y)my_func(x,y,f,g),-pi,pi,-pi,pi)
```

Any help or ideas please???

Comment: Please edit your post to include the integral you're trying to compute.

Comment: It would also help to show the actual code you're running (including the values of f and g which are causing problems) and the exact errors/warnings you receive. When I try it with 'high'ish values (f=g=100) I do not have an issue if i set MaxFunEvals high enough.

Comment: Try 0 and 130. Even if MaxFunEvals is set astronomically high it will not evaluate the integral. It gives: Non-finite result. The integration was unsuccessful. Singularity likely.

Comment: >> (quad2d(@(x,y)my_func(x,y,0,139),-pi,pi,-pi,pi,'MaxFunEvals',1e5));
Warning: Non-finite result. The integration was unsuccessful. Singularity likely. 
> In quad2d at 242

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check if this is a mathematical problem or a programming problem. For your inputs of f and g of 0 and 130, the edges of your integral do indeed go to infinity. Therefore it should be no surprise that matlab evaluates to infinity, because that is indeed the answer.

Now to be sure, it is possible for the edge of the integrand to go to infinity without the total integral also going to infinity, but if you plot the results as you approach the limit of pi, the total integral does not approach a limit and continues to rise as you approach pi.

```
z = zeros(1, 100);
dd = logspace(-8, -2, 100);
for i = 1 : 100
    d = dd(i);
    z(i) = quad2d(@(x,y)my_func(x,y,0,130),-pi+d,pi-d,-pi+d,pi-d);
end
plot(log10(dd), z)
```